get variable under Network tab on browser using jQuery
I have a simple search submission form on one page with the following code...
<form id="FormSearch" method="POST" class="customform" action="forum-search.php">
    <label for="SearchWord" class="topLabel SearchPage">Search Forum
        <input type="text" name="SearchWord" id="SearchWord" placeholder="Search...">
    </label>
</form>

When a search term is submitted, you are sent to forum-search.php which is where I want jQuery or JavaScript to handle the results of the search.
Under the network tab on my browser, I can see SearchWord: 'word searched' How can I use jQuery or JavaScript to access the SearchWord variable?

No, the POST data is sent to the web server, on which you apparently have PHP running (since your target is forum-search.php). It should be PHP that reads that search word, and then generates the HTML/JavaScript  based on that information. Your JavaScript can only access it if your PHP script handed that information back to the browser.

When I am sent to forum-search.php then check the Network tab, I can see the variable name and the variable that was sent. I wanted to know if jQuery or Javascript could access that data on the page forum-search.php

Yes, that is what you said in the question. And I have commented about that. Why do you repeat it? "I wanted to know if...": the answer is "No".

OK thanks for the answer, I got my solution from the message at the top suggesting the question was already answered on another post. I searched previously but did not see that post when searching. It answers my question.

Yes, I put it there.
